# sed throwing sed: -e expression #(number), char (number): unknown command: `(letter)'

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a shell script which reads some files and copy all the data from these files to other consolidated file.

This happens multiple times and previously copied data will not be copied again. For this i am saving the last copied line in a separate file and comparing it from the second time.

Flow of logic :

- For the first time, read individual files and copy the whole data except last line into the consolidated file. Saving the last copied line into a temporary file.

`sed '$d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile`

`tail -2 $file | head -1 > $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine`

- From second time, read last line from the temporary file and search for that line in individual file. When found, take all the lines from the next line and append to consolidated file.

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

consolidatedCSVFile=$1
endTime=$2

curdate=$(date +%s)

CSVFiles=${@:3}
CSVFiles=${CSVFiles[@]}

lastLines=_LASTLINES
lastLine=_LASTLINE

newMerge=false

# Returns 1 if Consolidated file is empty
[ -s $consolidatedCSVFile  ]
if [ $? == 1  ]
    then
        mkdir $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines
        newMerge=true
fi

testInProcess=false

if [ $endTime -ge $curdate  ]
    then
        testInProcess=true
fi

for file in $CSVFiles
do
if $newMerge ;
    then
        touch $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines5(basename $file)$lastLine
        sed $d $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        tail -2 $file | head -1 >   $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines5(basename $file)$lastLine
    else
        availableLastLine="`cat $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine`"
        if $testInProcess
            then
                sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile
                tail -2 $file | head -1 > $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines5(basename $file)$lastLine
            else
                sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        fi
fi

done

if  !  $testInProcess ;
then
    rm -rf $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines
fi
```

Sometimes, i get error as `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unknown command: 'X'`

> My guess

I am trying to combine the files generated by JMeter.
Sometimes, the files are generating data like `1439459065780,5,SOAP/XML-RPC Request,200,OK,ws test 1-3,text,true,267,3,3,5`

I think the problem is while `sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file  | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile` at `SOAP/XML`. Slash(/) could be problem here.

Comment: Also, it would be good if you could put the source of your scripts in as text instead of as images.  It's hard to search by text in an image, and it would be very hard for me to try to enter that script on my machine to debug it along with you

Comment: the script contains the symbol "~" which is resulting to imporper view of code.

Comment: can u plz suggest how to paste the text

Comment: If you put the code in the body and indent each line by 4 spaces it will format it for you and you should not have trouble with special characters.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more detailed help

Comment: At least keep the screen shots the same format.

Comment: @EricRenouf , can u try to debug the code and let me know where i am  going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked after modifying `availableLastLine`
to `availableLastLine=$(sed 's/\//\\\//' $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine)`.

Working Script :

```
#!/bin/bash

consolidatedCSVFile=$1
endTime=$2

curdate=$(date +%s)

CSVFiles=${@:3}
CSVFiles=${CSVFiles[@]}

lastLines=_LASTLINES
lastLine=_LASTLINE

newMerge=false

# Returns 1 if Consolidated file is empty
[ -s $consolidatedCSVFile  ]
    if [ $? == 1  ]
        then
            mkdir $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines
            newMerge=true
    fi

testInProcess=false

if [ $endTime -ge $curdate  ]
    then
        testInProcess=true
fi

for file in $CSVFiles
do
if $newMerge ;
    then
        touch $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines5(basename $file)$lastLine
        sed $d $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        tail -2 $file | head -1 > $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines5(basename $file)$lastLine
    else
        ## Replaced below line
        #availableLastLine="`cat $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine`"
        availableLastLine=$(sed 's/\//\\\//' $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine)
        if $testInProcess
            then
                sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile
                tail -2 $file | head -1 > $consolidatedCSVFile$1astLines5(basename $file)$lastLine
            else
                sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        fi
fi

done

if  !  $testInProcess ;
then
    rm -rf $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines
fi
```

> Possible error cases handled while merging of multiple files

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n******* $(date) *******"

echo "Arguments :: $@"

consolidatedCSVFile=$1

echo "consolidatedCSVFile :: $1"

endTime=$2
curdate=$(date +%s)

echo -e "endTime :: $2\n"

CSVFiles=${@:3}
CSVFiles=${CSVFiles[@]}

echo -e "Individual Files : ${CSVFiles[@]}\n"

lastLines=_LASTLINES
lastLine=_LASTLINE

newMerge=false

# Returns 1 if Consolidated file is empty
[ -s $consolidatedCSVFile ]
    if [ $? == 1 ]
        then
        newMerge=true
    fi

echo "newMerge? :: $newMerge"

if $newMerge ;
    then
        if [ ! -d $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines ]
            then
                echo "creating LASTLINES directory"
                mkdir $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines
        fi
fi

testInProcess=false

if [ $endTime -ge $curdate ]
    then
    testInProcess=true  
fi

echo -e "testInProcess? :: $testInProcess\n"

for file in $CSVFiles
do

echo -e "\nCurrent file in loop :: $(basename $file)"

if $newMerge ;
    then    
        # Returns 1 if file is empty
        [ -s $file ]
            if [ $? == 1 ]
                then
                    echo "File empty !!"
                            continue
            fi
        echo "creating LASTLINE file"
        touch $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine
        #sed '$d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        sed '1d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        echo "Last line to save :: $(tail -1 $consolidatedCSVFile)" 
        tail -1 $consolidatedCSVFile > $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine
    else
        # Returns 1 if file is empty
        [ -s $file ]
            if [ $? == 1 ]
                then
                    echo "File empty !!"
                            continue
            fi

        if [ ! -f $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine ]
            then
                echo "creating LASTLINE file"
                touch $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine
                #sed '$d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
                sed '1d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile
                echo "Last line to save :: $(tail -1 $consolidatedCSVFile)" 
                tail -1 $consolidatedCSVFile > $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine
                continue
            else
                availableLastLine=$(sed 's/\//\\\//' $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine)
                echo "Last line from file :: $availableLastLine"
        fi
        if $testInProcess
            then
                tempVar=`sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file | sed '$d'`
                #echo -e "\ntempVar ::\n$tempVar\n"
                    [ -z "$tempVar" ]
                    if [ $? == 1 ]
                        then
                            #sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile
                            echo -e "$tempVar" >> $consolidatedCSVFile
                            echo "Last line to save :: $(tail -1 $consolidatedCSVFile)"
                            tail -1 $consolidatedCSVFile > $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines/$(basename $file)$lastLine
                        else
                            echo "No last line to save"
                    fi
            else
                        sed '1,/^'"$availableLastLine"'$/d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
        fi
fi

done

if ! $testInProcess ;
then
    echo -e "\nRemoving LASTLINES folder"
    rm -rf $consolidatedCSVFile$lastLines
fi

echo -e "\n*************"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having gone through all your code, your intuition about that line seems spot on to me.  The variable is going to be expanded before the `sed` command is executed, so if you have `/` in the expansion it will terminate the pattern in `sed`.  You can use other characters than `/` as your separators, so if, say `_` is not going to show up in your data you could use that like

```
sed '1,_^'"$availableLastLine"'$_d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile
```

or you could skip the second sed with

```
sed -e '1,_^'"$availableLastLine"'$_d' -e '$d' $file >> $consolidatedCSVFile
```

Comment: do you mean the problem could be with second sed (sed '$d') ?

Comment: No, I think you're probably right that the first part is the problem, I was just saying that with sed you can give it multiple expressions to operate on, so you don't need a second instance of sed

Comment: tried using `sed '1,_^'"$availableLastLine"'$_d' $file | sed '$d' >> $consolidatedCSVFile` , but i get `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'`